# KivyMD KeyError on caller for MDDropdownMenu

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, keyerror, kivymd

I am trying to change my existing Kivy App to incorporate the nice looking KivyMD widgets.  I removed a `Spinner` for the `MDRaisedButton` with `on_release` `caller` for the `MDDropdownMenu` with a list of device names that has been paired via Bluetooth to a device (depending on the platform).  For this test example I only use the menu items list as shown in the `MDDropdownMenu` docs example.

For some reason I am receiving `KeyError: 'dev_button'` for the `MDRaisedButton` `id` on initialising the `MDDropdownMenu` properties.  The `__init__` method is within my root class that is in separate files named `indexui.py` and `indexui.kv` to the `main.py` and `main.kv` file.  But is imported in the `main.py` file and included in the `main.kv` file.  The App did run before changing the `Spinner`.

**indexui.py**

```
class RootLay(FloatLayout):
    this = ObjectProperty(None)  # App object
    bserial = ObjectProperty(None)  # Bluetooth variables starts
    recv_stream = ObjectProperty(None)
    send_stream = ObjectProperty(None)
    menu = ObjectProperty(None)
    rfsocket = ObjectProperty(None)
    device = ObjectProperty(None)
    pattern = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.device = None
        self.pattern = re.compile(r'[GNSTUkg,\s]')
        self.dev_list = []
        menu_items = [{"icon": "git", "text": f"Item {i}"} for i in range(5)]
        print(dir(self.ids))
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.ids.dev_button, items=menu_items, width_mult=4
        )
        self.menu.bind(on_release=self.menu_callback)
```

**indexui.kv**

```
<RootLay>:
    MDToolbar:
        pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'right': 1}
        title: "Bluetooth Weigh"
    MDRaisedButton:
        id: dev_button
        text: "SEE DEVICES"
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.76, 'right': 0.9}
        on_release: app.root.menu.open()
```

**main.py**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from views.indexui import RootLay
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Yellow"  # "Purple", "Red"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "600"
        # self.icon = 'bluetooth-connected_326502.png'
        root = ObjectProperty(RootLay())
        return root

    def on_pause(self):
        return True
    
MainApp().run()
```

**main.kv**

```
#:include views/indexui.kv

RootLay:
```

Can someone please help me to understand why there is a `KeyError`? The `MDRaisedButton` is within the `RootLay` class scope as a method.  I should therefore be able to access al its properties.

Comment: It looks like your `kv` is not being loaded. Are you explicitly loading the `kv`? is your `kv` file named `main.kv`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.  Yes I believe it is loading as the `main.kv` file has the same name as the App class.  I added the `kv` files code above.  Is there something I should do extra? Or something I am not importing correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are trying to access the `ids` of the `RootLay` class before they are available. I suggest delaying that access by using `Clock.schedule_once()` like this:

```
class RootLay(FloatLayout):
    this = ObjectProperty(None)  # App object
    bserial = ObjectProperty(None)  # Bluetooth variables starts
    recv_stream = ObjectProperty(None)
    send_stream = ObjectProperty(None)
    menu = ObjectProperty(None)
    rfsocket = ObjectProperty(None)
    device = ObjectProperty(None)
    pattern = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.device = None
        self.pattern = re.compile(r'[GNSTUkg,\s]')
        self.dev_list = []
        Clock.schedule_once(self.setup_menu)  # delay until ids are available

    def setup_menu(self, dt):
        menu_items = [{"icon": "git", "text": f"Item {i}"} for i in range(5)]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.ids.dev_button,
            items=menu_items,
            width_mult=4
        )
        self.menu.bind(on_release=self.menu_callback)
```

Comment: That is a very clever solution. Thanks!

Comment: If you add a callback function to the `menu_items` and not binding it as in my example, will it effect the function working or not?

Comment: That is `menu_items=[{'callback': self.menu_callback, 'text':  f"Item {i}"} for i in range(5)}]` instead of binding it to the `self.menu`.

Comment: The reason I am asking is because Erik Sandberg made an example using the `callback` in this way, but it does not work when the `callback` and `viewclass`  is  set to the `items` key.  It only works when it is set to the `callback` key on the `MDDropdownMenu` instance.  Within the `MDDropdownMenu` source code I also do not find a `viewclass` or `callback` that can be set on the `items` key of the `MDDropdownMenu` instance. So maybe it has been deprecated,

Comment: I am not aware of any way to include a callback in the `items` list, however, you can add `callback=self.menu_callback` to the `MDDropdownMenu()` call (and remove the `self.menu.bind` call).